# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, directory

I'm trying to get sub directories paths from a directory, but ignore some folders, the code below gives me this error,

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'

can anyone help?

```
Dim subdirectoryEntries() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("FsRoot") & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & readerClientList.GetString(0)).
Where(Function(name) Not name.EndsWith(folder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: What do you do with subDirectoryEntries?  Depending on the answer, you might be better to change its type to `IEnumerable(Of String)` rather than converting the result of `GetDirectories`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the result of the getdirectories where is a iqueryable result, you have to add an . and for example tolist or toarray or similar method to cast to this method.

Hope this help

Comment: Beautiful.    I was trying to use  list.TypeOf , running into this issue.  I was posting a new question and stumbled across this.